# Finding minimum of a function using fminbound method from scipy

Tags: python-3.x, scipy-optimize

I used `fminbound` method to find minimum of a function as below

```
from scipy import optimize

def f1(x):
  return x*x*x - 2*x + 0.5

optimize.fminbound(f1, 0, 1)
```

I wonder if instead of defining the function `f1()` separately, could I define that on-the-fly directly as parameter of `fminbound`. For example,

```
optimize.fminbound(<<define function here directly>>, 0, 1)
```

Any insight will be very helpful

Update based on answer from @Amadan

As @Amadan mentioned one way to achieve the same is using `lambda` function as below

```
optimize.fminbound(lambda x: x*x*x - 2*x + 0.5, 0, 1)
```

However it seems that above will only work if the function consists of just one line. In case function has multiple lines, then it fails like below

```
optimize.fminbound(lambda x: {a = x*x*x - 2*x
                              a + 0.5}, 0, 1)
```

Above fails. I have rather a function with multiple lines. So any generalisation will be very helpful.

Comment: The function is trivial enough that its minimum can be found analytically. But as to your central question of how to write it in one line: just... don't. Either a function is complex enough that it merits both iterative minimization and its own free-standing function with good argument names and typehints, or it merits neither.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

```
optimize.fminbound(lambda x: x*x*x - 2*x + 0.5, 0, 1)
```

Python lambdas have a quite a bit of a disadvantage compared to other languages, in that they can only consist of a single expression, but it works just fine for the example in the question.

Comment: Thanks. But it seems that this will only work if the function consists of just one line. In case function has multiple lines what can be done? I updated my original post with this issue

Comment: Nothing. Due to its particular indentation-based syntax, there is no way to make an anonymous multi-line function, except for `evil` hacks that I strongly recommend against. If you have a multi-line function, the approach at the top of the question is correct.

Comment: Also, note that `lambda` can only contain a single _expression_ (not even a statement), not a single _line_. You can have multiple statements in one line, using `;` as a separator (e.g. `a = x*x*x - 2*x; a + 0.5; return a`) — you _can't_ put those in a lambda. Meanwhile, you can split a single expression into multiple lines, like `x*x*x - <newline> 2*x + <newline> 0.5`, and (as long as it is in some parentheses) you _can_ put it into lambda.

Comment: Can you please tell a bit more about the `evil` hack?

Comment: There may be an easier way but I haven't found it: compile a string containing newline escapes, extract the function constant, turn it into a function: `scipy.optimize.fminbound(types.FunctionType(compile("def f(x):\n\ta = x*x*x - 2*x\n\ta + 0.5\n\treturn a", "", "single").co_consts[0], globals()), 0, 1)`. Please only ever use it if someone threatens with murder, otherwise forget you ever saw this.